# Why Goku uses all the transformations he has except Super Saiyan 3 in the tournament of power?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

is there any reason why Goku uses all the transformations he has in the tournament of power except super saiyan 3? So far he has used,

Super saiyan . Against Caulifla for example.

Super saiyan 2. Against Kale for example.

Super saiyan blue. Against the trio de dangers for example.

Super saiyan god. Against Dyspo for example.

Does super saiyan 3 has a disadvantage over all the other transformations or something?

Comment: As per the Dragon ball series, it has been shown that Super saiyan 3 takes lots of power, hence to preserve the stamina he hasn't use it. You can see in whole series he hasn't use SSJ3 for full time, only use for crucial times.

Comment: For example, when transformed first time to SSJ3 he fight for a while in that state and then retreated, when fighting kid boo, he need more time to power up again him self so he asked Vegita to take care for 10 minutes, also when he was showing SSJ3 to trunks and gotens we can see how much he tired.

Comment: The top 2 hardest ones to maintain Stamina wise are Blue and SSJ3, based on how the manga and anime have been presenting them. In the Manga, Goku Mastered Blue, meaning its stamina drain was cut down to almost nil, but we have not seen him purposefully suppress the SSJ3 aura, meaning he probably hasn't mastered it. By that standard, SSJ3 consumes more stamina than Blue does for Manga Goku (as of the Zamasu arc end). If the anime is even somewhat doing the same thing even indirectly, we could probably assume Red consumes less stamina than SSJ3 to maintain, but is way stronger with the God Ki

Comment: @Ryan interesting comment, post it as an answer and I'll vote it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because SSJ3 suppose to drag a lot of energy and it was shown when Future trunks came however I think it is not shown because we await for new form.

Answer (score 1):

Goku was probably trying to save his power so he wouldn't tire himself out.The reason he used super  saiyan blue is so he would have enough power to win